# Remove items from list - mixed object

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, list, user

I am trying to remove an item from a list but i have something wrong in my syntax. I am getting error:

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [List<User>].remove(Id)
```

Trigger Code:

```
trigger User on User (after insert, after update) {

    Public List<ID> HubsToReactivate = new list<ID>();
    Public List<ID> HubsToCreate = new list<ID>();
    List<User> users = new list<User>();

    //Handle new user creation and reactivation of inactive users. 
    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){

        For(User u: Trigger.new){
            users.add(u);
        }

        // Task 1 - Check for existing hubs
        List<BCS__c> findHubs = new list<BCS__c>([
            SELECT Id, Name, Title__c, User__c
            FROM BCS__c
            WHERE User__c IN :users
        ]);

        //Reactivate found hubs for users
        for(BCS__c b:findHubs){
            HubsToReactivate.add(b.Id);
        }

        //Create Hubs for new users. 
        List<User> newUsers = users.clone();
        //Remove anyone who we already found a BCS__c record for above.
        for(BCS__C b:findHubs){
            newUsers.remove(b.User__c);
        }


        //Call Future Method for DML operation
        future_New_User_Setup.reactivateHubs(HubsToReactivate);
        future_New_User_Setup.createHubs(HubsToCreate);


    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `Map<Id, User>` instead.

Comment: List.remove takes index as the parameter not an user object. change your for loop to for(integer i=0;i<findhubs.size();i++){newUsers.remove(i);}  Refer: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `Map` instead. Then you can remove based on a key.

```
Map<Id, User> newUsers = new Map<Id, User>(users.clone());
for (BCS__c record : findHubs) newUsers.remove(record.User__c);
```